# How to send a query to Azure Table REST API with Postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to make a GET request to Azure Table REST API with Postman.
I can make a working request with a C# program I found, but when I try to copy the same information into the Postman request it return the followign error:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

With the C# program I generate my UTC time and my Authorization code. 
The program will give me the following output:

> x-ms-date: Fri, 01 Nov 2019 10:13:26 GMT
>
> Authorization: SharedKeyLite username:e4IREMOVEDSOMELETTERST4Ag=
>
> Request URI: https://username.table.core.windows.net/MainTable(PartitionKey='akey',RowKey='130')

The generated output works in the C# program, because when I use:

```
    result = await Client.GetAsync(requestUri);
```

The result will give me the information of *(akey, 130)*.
When I pass them into postman it will still give me an error.
I **do** update the date in postman whenever I make a new authorized string.

My postman setup is as follows:
[image: postman]

I eventually want to make this request with the ESP32, so it might be a bit unrelated, but the ESP is giving me the same error. Any tips on setting the headers correct either for Postman or the ESP are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was within Postman itself. 
There has been an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4171) with the automatic URL encoding. 
When I went directly to the MainTable the code of Mauricio worked.

Answer (score 3):

to make this work first create two variables in your environment :

```
{{utcDate}}
{{authToken}}
```

Then create a new Get request and setup your headers like this :

```
x-ms-version             2015-12-11

x-ms-date                {{utcDate}}

Authorization            SharedKey resourceName:{{authToken}}

DataServiceVersion       3.0;NetFx

MaxDataServiceVersion    3.0;NetFx

Accept                   application/json;odata=nometadata
```

Finally, define a Pre-request Script :

```
var now = new Date().toUTCString();
pm.environment.set("utcDate", now);
var hcar = "/resourceName/TableName";
var verb = request.method;
var cntMd5 = "";
var cntType = "";
var mKey="<Your service key goes here>";

var text = verb + "\n" + (cntMd5 || "") + "\n" + (cntType || "") + "\n" + now + "\n" + hcar;

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(mKey);
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key);
var base64Bits = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);
pm.environment.set("authToken", base64Bits);
```

The reason for the variables is, authToken because you need a place holder to store the calculated token, utcDate because the same date in your header must be used to calculate your token.

Comment: I've tried this solution and it is very similair to my solution, but yours is automated. 
It's still not working and still giving me the error.
Could it be that the my GET url is incorrect?

Comment: Have you compared the authToken from my pre-request script with your manually generated token? is the token the same?

Comment: Also remember if the utcDate in your header do not match with the one used to generate the token, it may not work.

Comment: No they are not the same, but I think that should be the case because I generate a SharedKeyLite token. When I tweak the code with code from  [this](https://chriskirby.net/blog/working-with-the-azure-storage-rest-api-in-automated-testing) tutorial, I do generate the same key. 
Even with the same key it will still give me the error.

Regarding the same date, your code ensures that it will have the same UTCdate, right?